# Value doesn't get passed in angular custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a custom checkbox directive in angular js. i want to pass the index value to the js so that i can generate unique id for each checkbox when its used inside ng-repeat. for some reason i am not able to pass the ***idIndex*** value to the directive. can anyone tell me what would be the issue

**HTML**

```
  <ng-checkbox data-checked="notification.selected" idIndex="{{'nId-'+$index}}"></ng-checkbox>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .component("ngCheckbox", {
       template:
           '<div class="ng-control-checkbox">' +
           '<input id="$ctrl.idIndex" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="$ctrl.checked" class="checkbox">' +
           '<label for="$ctrl.idIndex">'+
           '<span data-ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>' +
           '</label>' +
           '</div>' +
           '',   

        bindings: {
            label: '=?',
            checked: '=',
            idIndex: '=?'
        },
        controller: function () {
            var $ctrl = this;
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: post a fiddle or working sample.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your directive attribute wrong in the case of `idIndex`,in Angular while creating directives and using them as E(element) or A(attribute) there are certain rules.You have to follow the '-' syntax when there is camelCase name for an attribute so make change your attribute to `id-Index`.

When the directive gets compiled the `id-Index` is converted into `idIndex` as in your isolated scope property.

```
 <ng-checkbox data-checked="notification.selected" id-Index="{{'nId-'+$index}}"></ng-checkbox>
```

There is also another way of doing this i.e change the attribute property to all lowercase in your directive like below

```
 bindings: {
            label: '=?',
            checked: '=',
            idindex: '=?'
        }
```

an still you can keep your HTML as it is like this

```
<ng-checkbox data-checked="notification.selected" idIndex="{{'nId-'+$index}}"></ng-checkbox>
```

Comment: It should be `id-index`

Comment: It works both ways , I've tried it out.Check this example https://plnkr.co/edit/sVLfJ7VHMTIk4oESuxwF?p=preview

Comment: It's just when Angular compiles the directive it makes it back to id-index in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I know, do follow conversation, don't encourage people to use it `id-Index`, It can lead to confusion.